# Let $M$ be the midpoint of side $AB$ of triangle $ABC$. Prove that $CM=AB/2$ if and only if angle $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$.

Tags: geometry

Let $M$ be the midpoint of side $AB$ of triangle $ABC$. Prove that $CM=AB/2$ if and only if angle $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By definition of $M$ the condition is equivalent to $MA=MB=MC$ i.e. $M$ being the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$. On the other hand, $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$ is equivalent to $BC$ being a diameter of the circumcircle.

Comment: Has it something to do with triangle's area?

Comment: @Estonian No, simply with the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

Comment: Solved it! :) Thanks for hint,